# Closure compiling Google Cast Javascript receiver app

Tags: google-cast

It appears a lot of externs are required for cast_receiver.js. Is there an existing extern file for cast_receiver.js?

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0):

For now, we don't have a public version of that available.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is there a plan to release the extern file?

Comment: As a general rule, we do not talk about or discuss future plans, sorry.